# How to change an input type button to "display=none" once clicked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, button

I have a button that I'm trying to hide once clicked. Also I just don't want to hide it I want it to `style='display:none'` once clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2020:

With [`addEventListener()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener) and [`querySelector()` being supported in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector), it can just be

```js
document
  .querySelector('#the-important-button')
  .addEventListener('click', ev => ev.target.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<button id="the-important-button">Click</button>
```

### Answer in 2012:

To make it unobtrusive and work on earlier IE and other modern browsers:

the HTML:

```
<button id="the-important-button">Submit</button>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var theButton = document.getElementById('the-important-button');

function hideTheButton() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

function addEvent(target, type, handler) {
    if (target.addEventListener) {
        target.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (target.attachEvent) {
        target.attachEvent('on' + type, function() {
            return handler.call(target, window.event);
        });
    } else {
        target['on' + type] = handler;
    }
}

addEvent(theButton, 'click', hideTheButton);
```

Note that `addEvent` is a generic function that works well on earlier IE and other modern browsers.  You can add other events similar to the last line of code above.

Sample on http://jsfiddle.net/W37Fb/5/

Comment: Beware of `.attachEvent`. It will set `this` to the `window` in the `hideTheButton` function. To make it work the same, you need to wrap an anonymous function around the `hideTheButton` call and invoke it like this: `hideTheButton.call(theButton, window.event);`

Comment: Very close, but get rid of the `event` parameter for the anonymous handler, and pass `window.event` to the actual handler. The `attachEvent` doesn't pass an event object. After that, you've got my +1. :-)

Comment: Ah I see, I saw the Dustin Diaz's version... the first version I used was from the JavaScript Definitive Guide 6th ed, p. 461...

Comment: thanks for your elaborate explination, and to everyone else who helped make this one...THANKS

Answer (score 6):

```
<button onclick="this.style.display='none';">a button</button>
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/uWfYk/

Comment: @user1480167: Just add `this.style.display="none";` to that code.

Comment: my answer uses `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` so that multiple handlers can be used

Comment: @動靜能量's answer looks a lot better than mine, I was just trying to keep it simple here.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `onclick` event to hide and apply style `display:none` using JS style, see below,

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Hide me" onclick="this.style.display='none'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/uWfYk/2/

Using jquery as follows

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    //do need full
    $(this).fadeOut();
})​
```

Using pure JS

http://jsfiddle.net/PeM2b/

Comment: OP didn't mention that jQuery is used, and you don't need to load a large DOM library for simple tasks.

Comment: This is just an example how to do it in jQuery, use or not its is upto the developer.

Comment: what do i do if i have more than one onclick?

Comment: @user1480167: Have you loaded the jQuery library? If not, this code won't work for you.

Comment: simple hide button when clicked but it has another onlick where it makes a div appear.